# How do the profiling tools perform a garbage collection on some button click or heap snapshot is taken?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Java profilers like *YourKit* or *JProfiler* almost always do have a button which says "*Perform GC*". The actual text on that button doesn't matter for this question. Also when we take heap snapshots in these tools  the JVM seems to be performing Garbage collection. But I know that `System.gc()` doesn't actually guarantee a garbage collection. So how do these profiler tools actually perform GC deterministically every time that special button is clicked or a heap snapshot is taken? Do they call some non java native methods internally to get around the limitation that `System.gc()` call doesn't force a GC every time ?

Answer (score 1):

The JVM exposes the [JavaTM Virtual Machine Tool Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/), which allows debuggers, profilers and similar tools to have much more in-depth access to the inner working of the VM than your program can have (for good reasons, too).

Answer (score 0):

Considering the **heap snapshot**, the Full GC is performed everytime you take a heap snapshot. This is independent from what `System.gc()` would do. You just send a "collect heap snapshot" signal and the VM will do the work - which includes a Full GC.

Considering the **Perform GC button**, the profile will just call the `System.gc()` method. Although this is not reliable it usually works. See [System.gc() vs GC button in JVisualVM/JConsole](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13305813/772000).